# jquery update div background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, background-image

I'm trying to update a background-image on the body element of a page, when I hover links with `data-*` attributes. It works like a charm but I can't find a way to create a smooth fade between the images when a link is hovered. Here is my code :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.link').hover(
  function() {
   var bg = $(this).data('fond');

   // alert(bg);

   $('body').css("backgroundImage", 'url(' + bg + ')');
  },
  function () {
             $('body').css("backgroundImage", 'url(http://sport-nc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/India_Surf_Tours_-_17__1_.jpg)');
        }
 );
});
```

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 background-image: url("http://sport-nc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/India_Surf_Tours_-_17__1_.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 transition: all 1s;
}

header {
 width: 50%;
 margin: 50px auto;
}

h1 {
 text-align: center;
}

nav {
 position: absolute;
 width: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
 padding: 50px;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
}

nav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 20px;
}

nav ul li a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
      <h1>Hover a link, bro</h1>
    </header>
        <!-- Main -->
        <main> 
          <nav class="main-nav">
            <ul>
              <li data-fond ="img/belharra.jpg" class="link"><a href="#">Belharra</a></li>
              <li data-fond ="img/jaws.jpg" class="link"><a href="#">Jaws</a></li>
              <li data-fond ="img/mavericks.jpg" class="link"><a href="#">Mavericks</a></li>
              <li data-fond ="img/nazare.jpg" class="link"><a href="#">Nazare</a></li>
              <li data-fond ="img/teahupoo.jpg" class="link"><a href="#">Teahuppo</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </main>
```

Bonus: Someone can explain to me why I had to use a second function when the mouse leave a link to give the body the original background image? I thought the `.hover()` method automatically put a toggle on the targeted element...

> The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during the time the mouse is within the element.

Thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: Thank you for the edit Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this can be done with a smooth fade effect.
A better way to achieve this is to put all your images in a div container in your html. All your images need to have a css opacity property to 0. In this way, you can easily change the opacity property beetween your images and have your smooth fade effect.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. As you said, I achieved it creating a new container with all the images, and changing their opacity according to the hovered links.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    margin:0;
    background-image: url("http://sport-nc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/India_Surf_Tours_-_17__1_.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

please change your url link `url("http://sport-nc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/India_Surf_Tours_-_17__1_.jpg");`
it is not correct

Comment: Sorry, what's not ok with the url?

Answer (score 0):

you can try your jquery like this.

```
$('body').fadeOut(1000).css("your code").fadeIn(1000);
```

following html,I have created to get an idea.think this may help to you.just copy and try it.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome !</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
 .myimage{
    width:500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
 }

 .myimage img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

 }


</style>


 <body>

  <div class="myimage">
    <img id="one" src="http://www.estero.co.nz/new/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/45901_new-zealand.jpg"/>
    <img id="two" src="http://www.timeforkids.com/files/styles/tfk_rect_large/public/2011-07/nz_ss5.jpg?itok=0m-TtEYy"/>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#one").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(1000);
    });
 });
</script>

 </body>
</html>
```